# Using TCP sockets in JBos's servlets

Tags: java, sockets, jakarta-ee, jboss, jboss7.x

Problem is next: there is a server, that using TCP sockets to connect with it and other server with JBoss. Is there any way to connect from JBos's servlet to other server with TCP socket?

I know that servlet couldn't connect to TCP socket directly. But maybe there is any way to create some lower level interface which would use sockets and available from servlet? Or some other JavaEE-magic exist which could solve my problem.

P.S. I am totally new to JBoss and Java EE.

P.P.S. JBoss AS 7.1.1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

yes there is.
you could write a JCA conenctor and inject that into your webapp, which could use it.
[JCA](http://itdevworld.wordpress.com/2008/08/26/java-connector-architecture-jca/) (java connector architechture) is a spec that allows Java EE servers to connect to external systems - like JDBC

Comment: Thanks a lot! A great variety of abbreviations and technologies in JEE confuse me a bit =)

Comment: @Avega - yeah its a bit hard to get into. unfortunately for you JCA, while definitely the correct technology to use when you want to files/sockets/threads from a j2ee stack, is a rather isoteric spec. i've linked to the best tutorial i know for it, but even that is a bit dated.